# floating point number from crypto.randomBytes() in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, cryptography

How do I convert the array of bytes returned from crypto.randomBytes into a to a floating point number? I'm writing a small replacement for Math.random()

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have a series of bytes randomly selected with uniform distribution over [0, 256). Take seven of those bytes, say a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>,… a<sub>6</sub>. Calculate (((((((a<sub>6</sub> % 32)/32 + a<sub>5</sub>)/256 + a<sub>4</sub>)/256 + a<sub>3</sub>)/256 + a<sub>2</sub>)/256 + a<sub>1</sub>)/256 + a<sub>0</sub>)/256.

Explanation: a<sub>6</sub> % 32 denotes the residue of a<sub>6</sub> modulo 32. This takes five bits of a<sub>6</sub>. Then division by 32 “shifts” these bits to the right of the radix point, eight new bits are added, a division by 256 “shifts” right eight bits, and so on until we have 53 bits.

This provides 2<sup>53</sup> possible results in [0, 1). It is possible to provide more since the floating-point resolution is finer as values get closer to zero, but then there are problems with uniformity and other issues.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, and [this](https://gist.github.com/AmrSaber/578c4c1b9d9c1f0a6ce5dd23bf9c3b4c) is a humble implementation of what you proposed.

Comment: I have a question though, why you specified 53 bits and not 52 bits that are the total bits for float mantissa?

Comment: @Argento: The floating-point format used in Javascript, IEEE-754 binary64, has 53 bits in the mathematical significand (the preferred term; “mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm). In bytes representing a floating-point number it is encoded with 52 bits in the primary significand field and one leading bit via the exponent field.