# Converting random bytes to an integer range - how?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get a random integer within a range by reading from crypto.randomBytes().

Now, my problem is that I do not know how to read integers from that byte stream. I imagine generating a range is simply a matter of 'throwing away' the ints not in range.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753019/floating-point-number-from-crypto-randombytes-in-javascript If you can get that working you can do Math.floor(randomFloat() * maxInteger) to get an integer between 0 and (maxInteger - 1).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get one 32 bit integer from `crypto.randomBytes` with the code below.  If you need more than one you can ask for more bytes from `crypto.randomBytes` and then use `substr` to individually select and convert each integer.

```
crypto.randomBytes(4, function(ex, buf) {
  var hex = buf.toString('hex');
  var myInt32 = parseInt(hex, 16);
});
```

Having said that, you might want to just use `Math.floor(Math.random() * maxInteger)`

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! Here's the one-line version: parseInt(crypto.randomBytes(4).toString('hex'), 16);

Comment: A good reason to use crypto.randomBytes() insteaad of just Math.random is becuase of this https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/330.html

Answer (score 6):

To obtain a **cryptographically secure and uniformly distributed** value in the `[0,1)` interval (i.e. same as `Math.random()`) in NodeJS

```
const random = crypto.randomBytes(4).readUInt32LE() / 0x100000000;
console.log(random); //e.g. 0.9002735135145485
```

or in the Browser

```js
const random = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / 0x100000000;
console.log(random);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const { randomInt } = await import('crypto');

const n = randomInt(1, 7);
console.log(`The dice rolled: ${n}`);
```

Now it is implemented in node itself
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randomint_min_max_callback

Comment: Looks like it's [cryptographically secure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67076035) as well